# How to loop Excel cells

Tags: excel, loops, powershell

I've been working on a PowerShell script to add users using `net user /add` from Excel cells. I've deemed it working perfectly.

```
cls
$FilePath = Read-Host 'Enter the file path to the Excel document'
$SheetName = Read-Host 'Enter the sheet name for the Excel document'

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($SheetName)

$AddUsers = {
  $Cell1 = Read-Host 'Enter the cell of the username'
  $Cell2 = Read-Host 'Enter the cell of the password'
  $Username = $WorkSheet.Range($Cell1).Text
  $Password = $WorkSheet.Range($Cell2).Text

  $correct = Read-Host 'Add user' $Username 'with password' $Password'?'

  if ($correct -contains 'yes') {
    cls
    net user $Username $Password /add /passwordchg:no
    $end2 = Read-Host "Continue adding users?"
    if ($end2 -contains 'yes') {
      cls
      &$AddUsers
    } else {
      cls
      Write-Host "End."
      Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
      $x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    }
  }
  if ($correct -contains 'no') {
    cls
    $end = Read-Host "End Script?"
    if ($end -contains 'yes') {
      cls
      Write-Host "End."
      Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
      $x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    } else {
      cls
      &$AddUsers
    }
  }
}

&$AddUsers
```

Now, I want to automate it. Instead of selecting each cell for the usr and psword each time, I want to state which cell to start at, and what to end at.

It would look a little bit like this:

A1 B1

---

A2    B2

---

A3     B3

I'd like to be able to say: Start at A1 B1, goto A3, B3. However, I have a few problems. I was thinking of using a `loop until` but I don't know how to make that work with cells. Is this possible? And how would I set it up to use A1 B1, then move to A2 B2? I have an idea on how to do that, but I'm not entirely sure how to loop through cells. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've done something similar in the past.  Used Excel's `concatenate` formula to create a semi-colon separated string which is put into a text file.  Next, a `FOR` loop in DOS batch is used to read that txt file and create the user accounts.  Finally, for additional bonus points, I used `Word` to mail merge and email the new account holders their details.  Please search and post your code/error, this isn't a code writing service.

Comment: why not working with csv?, powershell has a native support for that, you can then do whatever you want, if you will show your csv data structure i will show you how to use it for your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a starting point.  Alternatives would be to have this out side of AddUsers and pass the $Username and $Password as parameters to the AddUsers function.

```
$startAt = Read-Host 'Enter starting ROW (as in 1, Not A1)...? '
$endAt = Read-Host 'Enter ending ROW (again, not Cell just the row number)...? '

while ($startAt -le $endAt) {
   $Username = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($startAt,1).Text
   $Password = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($startAt,2).Text 
   # Add user or write to screen if you want to check the values
   $startAt++
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured a method myself last night, which is very crude, but it works for my purposes. I am just combining $cell+$loopcount into one variable, and increases loopcount each time in a for loop. I didn't know PowerShell allowed two different data types to be combined so easily...